# Hadamard theorem and length of geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I read  sevral times  in articles that:

"By Hadamard theorem, there is no closed  geodesics of length $2\pi$ in a space of sectional curvature $<0$?

Can someone give me a reference of this theorem, because i don't find it !

Thank you in advance

Comment: Consider a hyperboloid of one sheet, say $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. The central circle (at $z=0$) is a geodesic of length precisely $2\pi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin like said "Robert bell" below, may be i have to add an other condition ?

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is often called the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

One version of the theorem is that if a space is complete and non-positively curved, e.g. a complete Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature less than or equal to zero or a complete geodesic metric space that is locally CAT(0), then its universal cover is globally non-positively curved, e.g. CAT(0).

Without passing to the universal cover, you can have closed geodesics of length $2\pi$.  For instance, the orbit space of the Euclidean plane under the action of translation by $2\pi$ has such geodesics.  So, it's important to include the hypothesis that the space is simply connected for statement you write above.

Comment: Of course, your example is in a flat space, not a strictly negative-curved space, as the OP specified.

Comment: Thank you for calling attention to this.  The example can be modified as follows: take the hyperbolic plane modulo a hyperbolic isometry with translation length $2\pi$, e.g. the homothety $z \mapsto cz$ in the upper half-plane model, where $\log{c} = 2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a proof of the Cartan-Hadamard theorem for instance in do Carmo's book "Riemannian Geometry" or in Peterson's book with the same title. (Actually, most advanced RG textbooks will contain a proof.) Here is the full statement:

Theorem. Suppose that $M$ is a **complete simply-connected** Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $\le 0$ everywhere. Then for each point $p\in M$ the exponential map $\exp_p: T_pM\to M$ is a diffeomorphism.

To conclude that such $M$ cannot contain a closed geodesic of positive length ($2\pi$ is irrelevant), note that each nonconstant geodesic in $M$ (regarded as a set!) has the form $\exp_p({\mathbb R} u)$ for some $p\in M$ and a unit tangent vector $u\in T_pM$. By the CH theorem,  $\exp_p({\mathbb R} u)$ is diffeomorphic to the real line, hence, cannot be a loop.